# how do i install react native on my windows machine

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am trying to run this command npx react-native init AwesomeProject

When i try to install it i get this error

```
error Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@latest
```

I went online to search for the solution to this error but i was asked to clear my npm cache , i ran this code to clear the error i was unable to clear the cache as this was i got in my terminal

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
```

i ran npm verify i got this error

```
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache)
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.016s
```

i tried reinstalling react native and got the same error

Comment: did you get as far as `Need to install the following packages` prompt?

Comment: by the way - I just ran that on my windows machine and it worked fine - now I feel dirty having react on my system :p